# Let $f$ be monotonic increasing on $[a,b]$ If $\int_a^bf'(x)dx = f(b)-f(a)$ Show $f$ is absolutely continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, absolute-continuity

I tried to prove it by the definition of absolutely continouse:

Let $\{(a_i,b_i)\}_{i=0}^n$ be disjoint sub-interval on $[a,b]$

By Reimenn integral,

$\int_a^bf'(x)dx = \sum_{i=0}^nf'(t_i)(b_i-a_i)$ ,for any $t_i \in[a_i,b_i]$

Since f is differentiable, there exist $c_i\in[a_i,b_i] $ such that $\frac{f(b_i)-f(a_i)}{b_i-a_i} = f'(c_i)$
......

And then I think I am on the wrong direction. What else can I know from $\int_a^bf'(x)dx = f(b)-f(a)$

Help me please

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227685/monotone-increasing-continuous-function-with-int-ab-f-fb-fa-which-i).

Comment: I have seen this. But still thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Extend $f$ to be $f(a)$ for $x\leq a$ and $f(b)$ for $x\geq b$. Since $f$ is
increasing, for every $h>0$ we have%
\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{b}\frac{f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}\,dx &  =n{\biggl \{}%
\int_{b}^{b+\frac{1}{n}}f(x)\,dx-\int_{a}^{a+\frac{1}{n}}f(x)\,dx{\biggr \}}\\
&  \leq n\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{n}=f(b)-f(a).
\end{align*}
It follows from Fatou's lemma, that
$$
0\leq\int_{a}^{b}f^{\prime}(x)\,dx\leq\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{a}%
^{b}\frac{f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}\,dx\leq f(b)-f(a).
$$
With the same proof if $a<y<b$ you get
\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{y}f^{\prime}(x)\,dx  & \leq f(y)-f(a),\\
\int_{y}^{b}f^{\prime}(x)\,dx  & \leq f(b)-f(y).
\end{align*}
Adding these two inequalities gives
$$
\int_{a}^{y}f^{\prime}(x)\,dx+\int_{y}^{b}f^{\prime}(x)\,dx\leq
f(y)-f(a)+f(b)-f(y)=f(b)-f(a).
$$
Since by hypothesis $\int_{a}^{b}f^{\prime}(x)\,dx=f(b)-f(a)$, it follows that
both inequalities must be equalities, that is,
$$
f(y)=f(a)+\int_{a}^{y}f^{\prime}(x)\,dx
$$
for every $y\in\lbrack a,b]$. Now you need to prove that if $g\geq0$ is
integrable, then the function
$$
h(y)=\int_{a}^{y}g(x)\,dx
$$
is absolutely continuous.

Comment: I don't understand the equality of second line. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: Break up the two integrals and in the first integral make the change of variables $z=y+\frac1n$. The integrals from $a+\frac1n$ to $b$ cancel out

Comment: Maybe you mean $z = x+1/n$?

Comment: I got it. Thank you!

Comment: How do we prove the final statement?

Answer (score -1):

the function is differentiable on that interval, so it has to be continuous. and continuous functions are absolutely continuous on an interval. you could use the definition of absolute continuity to prove that a continuous function is absolutely continuous on an interval.

Comment: This is not correct.

Comment: which part of the answer?

Comment: continuity on an interval does not imply absolute continuity, even if the interval is closed and bounded. E.g. $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x\sin\dfrac1x,\quad & x\in(0,1]\\ 0,\quad &  x=0\end{cases}$$ is not absolutely continuous.

Comment: But that function is not differentiable at 0.

Comment: no it isn't. But that's a counterexample to your assertion that continuity on a compact interval implies absolute continuity.

Comment: jnyan you are confusing uniform continuity with absolute continuity. A continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous, but not absolutely continuous as Vim's example shows. Anyway, an increasing function is only differentiable a.e. and not everywhere, so it can have countably many discontinuity points

Comment: Oh ok. But before that, the function is monotonic increasing and continuous. And such functions are absolutely continuous on an interval if they are defined everywhere on the interval. I just skipped mentioning that part.

Comment: no the Cantor function is increasing and continuous but not absolutely continuous....